Updating SSAS roles access with PowerShell and XMLA script
I made a script to grant rights to Data sources for each role on a SSAS server.
If just 1 role exists on the server, it works fine, but with more not, the problem is that the DataSourcePermissionID of the Object and the ID, NAME of the DataSourcePermission are changing on each roles, making the modification by script impossible to make:
The Data Source:

Detail of Data Sources permission of "Role":

In the Generated script of Role it's about "DataSourcePermission"
<Batch xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine' Transaction='true'>
<Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>AdventureWorks_multidim_v2</DatabaseID>
    <DataSourceID>Adventure Works2019</DataSourceID>
    <DataSourcePermissionID>DataSourcePermission</DataSourcePermissionID>
  </Object>
  <ObjectDefinition>
      <DataSourcePermission xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
      <ID>DataSourcePermission</ID>
      <Name>DataSourcePermission</Name>
      <RoleID>Role</RoleID>
      <Read>Allowed</Read>
    </DataSourcePermission>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>
</Batch>

But for "Role 1":

In the generated script the DataSourcePermissionID is "DataSourcePermission 1"
<Batch xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine' Transaction='true'>
<Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>AdventureWorks_multidim_v2</DatabaseID>
    <DataSourceID>Adventure Works2019</DataSourceID>
    <DataSourcePermissionID>DataSourcePermission 1</DataSourcePermissionID>
  </Object>
  <ObjectDefinition>
      <DataSourcePermission xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
      <ID>DataSourcePermission 1</ID>
      <Name>DataSourcePermission 1</Name>
      <RoleID>Role 1</RoleID>
      <Read>Allowed</Read>
    </DataSourcePermission>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>
</Batch>

So I assume that all the DataSourcePermissionID are differents between roles, but how to get the list of those DataSourcePermissionID ?
I tried with the script bellow but there is 0 permission:
Permissions pour le rôle 'Role 1' :

The script:
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"

# Define parameters
$serverName = "LENOVODECIDEOM\LOCAL"
$databaseName = "AdventureWorks_multidim_v2"
$dataSourceName = "Adventure Works2019"
$roleName = "Role 1"

$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.Connect($serverName)

$database = $server.Databases.FindByName($databaseName)

$role = $database.Roles.FindByName($roleName)

if ($role -ne $null) {
    Write-Output "Permissions pour le rôle '$roleName' :"

    foreach ($dataSourcePermission in $role.DataSources) {
        Write-Output "ID de Permission: $($dataSourcePermission.ID) - Source de Données: $($dataSourcePermission.Name) - Type de Permission: $($dataSourcePermission.GetType().Name)"
    }
} else {
    Write-Output "Rôle '$roleName' non trouvé dans la base de données '$databaseName'."
}

$server.Disconnect()

